# Prove that $(x_{n})$ is bounded above by $4$

Tags: induction

> Let, $(x_{n})$ be a sequence define recursively by,
>   $x_{1}=1$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n}+\sqrt{3x_{n}})$.
>   Verify that the sequence is bounded above by 4.

By induction we have:

for $n=1$,

$ x_{1}=1<4$.

Now suppose that $x_{n}<4$ is true for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let see if $x_{n+1}<4$ is true:

By definition of $(x_{n})$ we have,
$$\frac{1}{2}(x_{n}+\sqrt{3x_{n}})<4$$
$$x_{n}+\sqrt{3x_{n}}<8$$

By the hypothesis, $x_{n}<4$:
$$x_{n}+\sqrt{3x_{n}}<4+\sqrt{12}$$

But now, what can I conclued? Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write "by definition of $(x_n)$ we have, ...", that is incorrect.  That's the desired conclusion, not a fact in your arsenal.

Here's how to fix this.  Because $x_n<4$, $3x_n<12<16$.  Hence $x_n+\sqrt{3x_n}<4+\sqrt{16}=8$.  Hence $\frac{1}{2}(x_n+\sqrt{3x_n})<\frac{1}{2}(8)=4$.  Now we use the definition above to conclude $x_{n+1}<4$, as desired.

Comment: When you chose $16$ it was with the propose of geting $8$? The true is that this sequence converges to $3$, so any number greater or equal to $3$ will bounded the sequence above.Thanks

Comment: One more question. Can I use induction to disprove that this sequence is not bounded above by $2$?

Comment: The purpose of 16 is to get 8, yes, because 16 has a nice square root.  To disprove that it's bounded above by 2, just take successive terms until you find one bigger than 2.

Answer (score 1):

After Induction hypothesis,for $n+1, x_{n+1}= 1/2 \times (x_n +\sqrt{3x_n}) < 1/2\times (4 + \sqrt{3\times4})= 1/2 \times(4+ 2\sqrt{3})= 2+\sqrt{3}<4.$